# Upgrade Cordova 2.6.0 to newest version for Android

Tags: android, eclipse, node.js, cordova, upgrade

I developed a cordova app on 2.6.0. Now I have to upgrade it to 3.5.1 or higher since Google Play Store sent me a mail to do so.

Now I installed the newest version of Cordova by npm install -g cordova and created a new project in the right (old) namespace. I added all plugins, copied the old www-files to the new www folder and added the android platform.

Back in Eclipse (Juno) I imported the project and tried to build it. Eclipse tells me to solve all errors firstly. After all I realized that all files under src were marked with errors.

[image: Eclipse Juno with errors in src folder]

I searched the web but I could not get any information on what is going wrong...

What would be the right way to find out what is going wrong and how to solve this errors probably?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: did you add the cordovaLib project too?

Comment: yes I did. I'm sure that I can't use the old plugins anymore but I can't find any step by step tutorials on how to migrate a pre 3.0 project to a post 3.0.

Comment: The easiest way is just to create a new cordova project, put your www files on the root www folder of your new folder and then try it. You'll get errors on logcat due to the missing plugins, so you install one by one using the CLI

Comment: Yes, that's what I did... I created a new project, copied all www-files to the root www folder and added android. Before I added all used plugins.

Comment: but how did you added the plugins? you have to use the CLI

Comment: I used the CLI for all steps to create a new project and then added the www-files to root www folder and added android platform

Comment: try to run the project from the CLI too with cordova run android, your problems seems related to eclipse, but you don't really need eclipse at all